# Stuck with making Kakurasu game

Tags: java, swing

We are learning in school java graphic and now we have to build a game called Kakurasu (https://www.brainbashers.com/showkakurasu.asp)

I'm so stuck and I don't know how to do it.

As far as I came. I've done a frame with a panel inside a panel which has 7x7 buttons that change from 0 to 1 and from white to green when pressed. The idea is that I make the first raw on the top and on the left to be the numbers 1-5 and then on the bottom and right side the random generated numbers.

This is my first code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Start {

public static JButton[][] gumbi;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    buttons = new JButton[7][7];
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Kakurasu");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel playingField = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7, 7));
    Listner1 p = new Listner1(buttons);

    panel.add(playingField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    window.add(panel);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            buttons[i][j] = new JButton("0");
            playingField.add(buttons[i][j], BorderLayout.CENTER);
            buttons[i][j].addActionListener(p);
            buttons[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setSize(500, 500);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

}
```

This is my second code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Poslusalec1 implements ActionListener {
public JButton[][] buttons;

public Listner1(JButton[][] gumbi) {
    this.buttons = buttons;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

    String tmp = button.getText();
    int n = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
    n += 1;
    if (n == 2) {
        n = 0;
    }
    button.setText("" + n);

    if (button.getBackground() == Color.WHITE) {
        button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
            if (button == buttons[i][j]) {
                System.out.println(i + ", " + j);
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Is it possible to assign different actionlisteners to different buttons inside a gridlayout?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The button values and answers are [not random](https://www.brainbashers.com/kakurasuhelp.asp).

Answer (score 4):

> I'm so stuck and I don't know how to do it.

To solve any computer problem, you break the problem down into smaller and smaller problems, until you're comfortable that you can code each small problem.

Generally, when coding a GUI, you should use the [model / view / controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

In Java Swing, this means:

1. The view may read values from the model.
2. The view may not update the model.
3. The controller updates the model.
4. The controller repaints / revalidates the view.

So, let's create a model for a JButton.  The model will hold the across value of the JButton, the down value of the JButton, and the background color of the JButton.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;

public class KakurasuCell {

    private final int acrossValue;
    private final int downValue;

    private Color backgroundColor;

    public KakurasuCell(int acrossValue, int downValue, Color backgroundColor) {
        this.acrossValue = acrossValue;
        this.downValue = downValue;
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    public Color getBackgroundColor() {
        return backgroundColor;
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(Color backgroundColor) {
        this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    public int getAcrossValue() {
        return acrossValue;
    }

    public int getDownValue() {
        return downValue;
    }

}
```

This is a Java object.  It holds multiple types of values.

Now, we create another model for a grid of JButtons.  You should recognize this from your code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;

public class KakurasuGrid {

    private int gridWidth;

    private KakurasuCell[][] cells;

    public KakurasuGrid(int gridWidth) {
        setGridWidth(gridWidth);
    }

    public int getGridWidth() {
        return gridWidth;
    }

    public void setGridWidth(int gridWidth) {
        this.gridWidth = gridWidth;
        this.cells = new KakurasuCell[gridWidth][gridWidth];
        setCells();
    }

    public KakurasuCell[][] getCells() {
        return cells;
    }

    private void setCells() {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridWidth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridWidth; j++) {
                KakurasuCell cell = new KakurasuCell((j + 1), (i + 1),
                        Color.GRAY);
                cells[i][j] = cell;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This should be enough to get you started.  You still need to create the answers, create the GUI, and add the controller methods.